# How to exit main script when first sub process stopped?

Tags: bash

There are many three processes(proc1~3.sh) running in background. I want to exit/stop all these program when one of these program exit error. Here are my simple approach, but it still have following issues:

1. It can not stopped other background programs when one exit the error
2. It can not stopped when the first background processes exit error.

The sample script is:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
proc1.sh &
pid1=$!
proc2.sh &
pid2=$!
proc3.sh &
pid3=$!

if ! wait $pid1 ; then
  echo "Err: proc1 stopped"
  exit 1
fi

if ! wait $pid2 ; then
  echo "Err: proc2 stopped"
  exit 1
fi

if ! wait $pid3 ; then
  echo "Err: proc3 stopped"
  exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Why not use `wait -n`?

Comment: Might be better to write this in another language, such as C or Python

Comment: Agree with JoelFan. Bash doesn't have a lot of flexibility with multi-processes and conditional logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution is to use `GNU parallel`

```
parallel -j3 --halt 2 bash ::: proc[1-3].sh
```

- `-j3` runs 3 jobs in parallel
- `--halt 2` exits when the first job fails and kills remaining running jobs